# Prove that if $\ker(T) \subseteq \ker(S)$, then $S = kT$ for some $k\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $V$ is a finite dimension linear space with dimension $n$, and
>   that $S,T: V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are linear transformations such
>   that $\ker(T) \subseteq \ker(S)$. What are the possible values of
>   $rank(T)$? Show that $S = kT$ for some $k\in \mathbb{R}$.

We have by the rank-nullity theorem that:

$$rank(T) + \dim(\ker(T)) = \dim(V)$$

So that: $rank(T) + \dim(\ker(T)) = n$

The only information we're given is that $\ker(T) \subseteq \ker(S)$. Does this mean that $\dim(\ker(T))$ can be anything from $0$ to $n$, so that the $rank(T)$ can also be anything from $0$ to $n$?

---

For the second part, showing that $S = kT$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$, I'm not really sure how to prove this. I know that $\ker(S)$ represents a basis for the elements that get mapped from $V$ to $0 \in \mathbb{R}$, and the $|\ker(T)| \le |\ker(S)|$, but I don't see how we can prove that $S = kT$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** As $\text{Im } T\subset \Bbb R$, the possible values for $\dim \ker T $ are $\dim  V$, $\dim V - 1$.
Split the analysis in two cases.
For the case
$
\dim V - 1
$ consider a vector $v$ such as
$$
V = span(v)\oplus \ker T
$$

Comment: What does "$\oplus$" mean?

Comment: @Parker this is the direct sum of subspaces: see definition 4.10 here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Combining_Subspaces

Comment: @mookid: why can't the kernel be of lower dimension than dimV-1?

Comment: @Functional_Analysis because $Im T\subset \Bbb R$.

Comment: What does $im T \subset \mathbb{R}$ mean? How do we know this?

Comment: $Im T = T(V)$ is a subset of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: So why does this mean $\dim \ker T$ has to be $\dim V$ or $\dim V-1$?

Comment: @Parker iit is a subspace of $\Bbb R$ which is itself of dimension 1.

Comment: @mookid: And how does V=span(v)⊕kerT implies S=kT?

Comment: @Functional_Analysis $S$ and $T$ are in that case characterized by their value on $v$.

Answer (score 0):

The second part is not true.

Take $n=3$, $(u,v,w)$ a basis and:

- $T$ defined by $T(u)= 0$, $T(v)=v$ and $T(w)=w$.
- $S$ defined by $S(u)= 0$, $S(v)=0$ and $S(w)=w$

Comment: Sorry. I'm wrong. I noticed too late that your linear transformations are supposed to be linear forms...